# Skype for Business Bot - always "presence unknown"

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

Is there any way to set up the presence of a Bot (created with Bot Framework and registered as explained at the Bot Framework Portal), to avoid the "presence unknown"?
[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue for Skype for Business channel, as it is currently in developer Preview state. We are currently working to fix this issue.

To track this issue, see: [[Microsoft/BotBuilder] Bot status is "Unknown" on Skype for Business #3017](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3017)

Comment: A over year later and the answer is still "This is in preview." Thanks Skype for Business team. :-/